# How to disable Gtalk chat history?

Tags: google-talk, chat-history

Am I missing something or is there no way to disable Gtalk history by default? Clearing separate conversations is a pain. If history can't be turned off, is there at least a way to wipe the whole Gtalk history at once somehow?

(using android2.2)

thank you

Comment: What version of Talk do you have?

Comment: it's gtalk version 1.3

Comment: I think the only way is to do it for each conversation, alternatively next time you start a new chat you could use the option do go off the record (haven't try that though).

Comment: @janfsd - off the record means something like 'off the server record'.. unfortunately has nothing to do local history.. oh well, we'll just have to wait for some better days I guess =)

Comment: Oh, good to know that it will still be in the local history. I have tried wiping the data for talk also but still did not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signing out and exiting (may need to check the task manager to make sure it's closed) should clear the local history.

Comment: nope, does not work.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: works :D thnx =)

Answer (score 1):

Check ReChat (Android chat): http://refineandroid.doodlekit.com/
- Facebook, Google Talk, basic Jabber/XMPP;
- multiple accounts at once;
- plain/bubble views. Customize avatar/font sizes.
- font packs (download separate apk to keep memory).
- full Unicode support;
- favorites (always in contact list);
- customize income message notification: default sound/your sound file, LED, vibration, status bar notification.
- chat history. Export (email) selected messages, open chat messages, whole history for a contact, whole history for all contacts. Archive attachment with 7zip.

Facebook features:
- all non-chat permissions are revoked, customize period, "revoke now".
- upload image/short video (several share options)
- send image/short video to a contact (private wall post).
- send message to a contact (as a private event or private wall post).
- set status message.

Google Talk features:
- showing total count of unread emails;
- marking contacts with unread emails;
- new email notification;
- list of unread emails subjects (without content);
- add/remove contacts.

Basic Jabber/XMPP features:
- add/remove contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off gtalk logging via Gmail, Settings > Chat > Never save chat history. To close all chat windows, you can use (in the gtalk application) option button > More > Close all chats.

Comment: chat history is already turned of in my gmail account, and when I use gtalk app on android - it still keeps history logs

Comment: You'd think Google would've made the app check for this setting or something.